# change color of ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have de following array:

```
size=5;
Initial = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {size, size}]*2 - 1;
```

to visualize it I use the following code:

```
ArrayPlot[Initial, ColorRules -> {1 -> White, -1 -> Black}]
```

I would like to highlight some points of the arrangement in the figure, for example:

```
{{4, 1}, {4, 3}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}, {4, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {4, 4}}
```

How would that be done?

Comment: You can give a list of colors to array plot using `Initial/.{1->White,-1->Black}` and then wrap this in `ReplacePart` `ArrayPlot[
 ReplacePart[ Initial /. {1 -> White, -1 -> Black},
  {{4, 1}, {4, 3}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}, {4, 2}} -> Red
  ]
 ]`. Is this what you're looking for? You could also generate the colors explicitly using `initColor=RandomChoice[{White,Black},{size,size}]` and then use `ReplacePart`.

Answer (score 2):

```
size = 5;
SeedRandom[1]
Initial = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {size, size}]*2 - 1;
parts = {{4, 1}, {4, 3}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}, {4, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {4,  4}};

ArrayPlot[MapAt[Red &, Initial, parts],  ColorRules -> {1 -> White, -1 -> Black}]
```

[image]

Replace `Red&` with `RandomColor[]&` to get

[image]